# Can't find new controller created

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I everyone I've created a new Controler inside my App\Controllers\Admin folder and I already have two files called AdminInquiriesController and AdminUsersController.

When I run my app it says that

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminNewsController does not exist
```

I don't undersantd. In all my 3 files inside this folder I'm using the namespace namespace

```
App\Http\Controllers
```

if it's working for the others why is not working for this?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Manager\InquiryManager;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use function GuzzleHttp\json_decode;
use App\Model\InquiryStatus;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Manager\UserManager;

class AdminInquiryController extends Controller {

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers ;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Manager\NewsManager;

class AdminNewsController extends Controller {
```

In my route file..

```
// inquiries
    Route::get('/admin/inquiries', 'AdminInquiryController@search');

// news
    Route::get('/admin/news', 'AdminNewsController@search');
    Route::post('/admin/news/new', 'AdminNewsController@create');
```

I know this is so silly but I'm not understanding what's happening...

[image]

Comment: Maybe you wanted App\Http\Controllers\Admin folder instead

Comment: Yes but why is working in my other two files without that??? This error is raised when I open a href with /admin/news

Comment: Maybe you have them duplicated in the right folder X-D

Comment: Because your other two controllers are in the `Controllers` folder and not in the `Admin` subfolder.

Comment: Nop, they are in folder admin as well

Comment: We don't have your source code. So compare your controller that does not work with the ones that work. But anyway, all of them should have the namespace: `App\Http\Controllers\Admin` if they exist in the `Admin` folder.

Comment: Another thing to check is if the file, and the class name are the same. For example you might have `AdminNewsController.php` but then a `class NewsController`

Comment: I've updated my question with new code pls see

Comment: You say they exist in the Admin folder, and yet you are using a wrong namespace.

Comment: I'm not understanding how they are working and this isnt

Comment: I suggest you generate these stuff like Models, Controllers and Migrations with the artisan commands. It makes it consistent and prevents it from some errors as just duplicating and changing names.

Comment: I've created this controller using the command php artisan make:controller AdminNewsController --parent=Admin but the parent option doest not exist so I've created the controller and moved into Admin folder..

Answer (score 1):

You should to define namespace in your controller file;

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin ;
```

Also change your web.php route file to

```
Route::get('/admin/news', 'Admin\AdminNewsController@search');
```

Or you can define namespace in routes group by

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
 Route::get('/admin/news', 'AdminNewsController@search');

}
```

Also you have to put

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
```

In your controllers files in Admin folder

Comment: I've used that and I've the same error.. 

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin ;

Comment: So in your route put ```Route::get('/admin/news', 'Admin\AdminNewsController@search'); ```

Comment: Now it says Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Controller' not found

Comment: You need to import the controller that you are extending. So put `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` at the top, below the namespace.

Comment: make sure that your folder name is not `admin` but it is `Admin` uppercase. And blindly helping won't work. Maybe share a screenshot from your project structure.

Comment: I've uploaded a image of my project structure and of the code

Comment: put 
```use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
``` in your controllers inside Admin folder

Comment: Nothing changed, now even News Controller is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a second forward slash when writing model location

something like this

```
 --model=App\\Models\\ModelName
```